# Ways to achieve "Hat Trick"?

Tags: achievements, slime-rancher

The *Hat Trick* achievement requires you to gather three Gold Plorts from a single Gold Slime. A Gold Plort is obtained when hitting a Gold Slime with any kind of food or plort, but if the slime then hits a wall, it seems to instantly vanish.

I've never been able to get more than one plort from a single Gold Slime, so what are some tricks to get three?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The most effective way I've found is to shoot a lot of food *behind* the Gold Slime, and then hit it straight on. When hit, the Gold Slime will bounce backwards into the food you've laid before, which counts as hitting it again and will make it drop additional Gold Plorts. Being above the slime helps a lot when trying to do this.

Alternatively, spending ridiculous amounts at the 7Zee Rewards Club will eventually grant the player the Golden Sureshot, which makes Gold Slimes drop three plorts instead of one.

One more way is to find a Gilded Ginger in the Glass Desert, which will cause Gold Slimes to drop five plorts.

Answer (score 1):

Reading up on the achievement many people suggest getting a considerable distance away from the golden slime and hitting it with food so it is less likely to notice you being there. They also suggest try being a higher elevation than the slime.

If that way doesn't work there is another way that I read about on the steam forums for the game.

Taken from: https://steamcommunity.com/app/433340/discussions/0/358417008725609519/

> Instead, do you know where the second Rock Gordo is? After it pops, it'll spawn 3 gold slimes, and then you'd have to shoot at them and hope for the best.
>   If you want to do it the normal way, after a gold slime spawns, shoot at it when it's against a wall, so it hits the wall and it's unable to run away. Do the same thing two times then.

So if the first way doesn't work the second option may be your best bet.

Good luck those gold slimes are very crafty.

Comment: The slimes that spawn from gordos are random, so that won't work. As I've said in the question, pushing a Gold Slime against a wall just makes it disappear entirely for me, so I believe I'm missing something.

Comment: Perhaps the sniper approach would work then by hitting them at a long distance.

Comment: I don't know why I said the slimes from gordos are random, that is entirely false. I believe the three Gold Slimes have been changed since then, though.